# Reduce Redis cluster to single GCP memorystore

Tags: redis

I have 3 redis instance with redis. One is the master and the other two, are the slaves. I have connected to master node and get info by redis-cli with INFO command. I can see the parameter cluster_enabled:0 and

#Replication

role:master
connected_slaves:2
slave0:ip=xxxxx,port=6379,state=online,offset=15924636776,lag=1
slave1:ip=xxxxx,port=6379,state=online,offset=15924636776,lag=0

And the keyspace, each node has different dbs. I need to migrate all data to a single memorystore in GCP but I don't know how. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Where are your 3 redis instances currently hosted?

Comment: In GCP compute as instances

Comment: Do you want the new memory store to be a Redis database too?

Comment: Yes, I want to migrate the three instances to a single memorystore

Comment: What is the approximate size of the DBs on both your redis slave instances combined?

Comment: @EMG Can you have a look at this [link](https://blog.teemo.co/from-redis-to-memorystore-a-migration-path-dcd49c84a66a). This talks about data migration from Redis to Memorystore using Cloud Dataflow and Pub-Sub topic

Comment: Thanks, I will check it

Answer (score 1):

Since the two nodes are slaves and clustering is not enabled, you only need to replicate the master node.  [RIOT](https://developer.redis.com/riot/index.html#_riot_redis) is a great tool for migrating data in and out of Redis.

However, if you say DB by node do you mean redis DB that you access by [select](https://redis.io/commands/select)?  In that case you'll need to prefix keys as there may be overlap between the keysets of the DBs.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the RIOT tool. So, this kind of architecture means I have the same databases in each node? So, if I migrate only master node to memorystore, I won't lose data, is that rigth?

Answer (score 1):

I think setting up another Redis cluster in a single node configuration is the least of your worries.

The real challenge for you would be migrating all your records over to the new setup. This is not a simple question to answer and would depend heavily on multiple factors:

- The total size of your data being migrated
- Is this is a live Database in production
- Do you want to keep the two DB schemas in your new configuration separate?

Comment: I want to create a single memorystore to replace the 3 instances

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I believe currently your Redis Instances are hosted on Google [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute).

And you are looking to migrate to [Memorystore for Redis](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis).

As mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/cloud-memorystore-adds-import-export-and-redis-4-0), you can leverage Redis snapshots for this. It provides you step-wise instructions on how to achieve this, leveraging GCS buckets as transient storage.

> import data into Cloud Memorystore instances using RDB (Redis Database Backup) snapshots, as well as back up data from existing Redis instances.